# golang connection does not write until i close the connection or exit my client app

Tags: go, tcp

I am new to golang and I am trying to build a simple TCP server and client in go. 
The client sends a message to server "hello from client" and will wait for the server to respond
with the message "Successfully processed". Problem is the client is not flushing the data till I call conn.Close() or hit CTRL+C on the client, if I hit CTRL+C or close the connection the client exits but does not wait for the server's message. The server gets stuck at this line

```golang
n, copyErr := io.Copy(temp, conn)
```

Can someone please help me out with this.

client.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
)

func writeMessage(conn net.Conn) {
    msg := "Hello from Client"
    _, writeErr := conn.Write([]byte(msg))
    if writeErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Write error", writeErr)
    }


}

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Dial error", err)
    }
    writeMessage(conn)

    msg, err := ioutil.ReadAll(conn)
    fmt.Println("Received message", string(msg), "from", conn.RemoteAddr())
}
```

server.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    localAddr := conn.LocalAddr()
    fmt.Println("Handling connection for", localAddr)

    temp := new(bytes.Buffer)
    n, copyErr := io.Copy(temp, conn)

    if copyErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Copy error:", copyErr)
    }

    fmt.Println("Processed", n, "bytes")
    conn.Write([]byte("Successfully processed"))

}

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating TCP server")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Listening on port :8080")

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Connection error")
        }
        handleConn(conn)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code stucks on `n, copyErr := io.Copy(temp, conn)` because it doesn't receives EOF until incoming connection is closed(either by call to `Close()` or shutting down the program). In your case, you want to close only writing side of connection. For that, `TCPConn` implements [`CloseWrite`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.CloseWrite) method. Here is example, how you can use it:

```
func writeMessage(conn net.Conn) error {
    if  cw, ok := conn.(interface{ CloseWrite() error }); ok {
        defer cw.CloseWrite()
    } else {
        return fmt.Errorf("Connection doesn't implement CloseWrite method")
    }

    msg := "Hello from Client"
    _, writeErr := conn.Write([]byte(msg))
    if writeErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Write error", writeErr)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks :+1 this worked ! but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @Shubhangb Not that i know of or can came up with right now)